# Unload LD_PRELOAD without restart process

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload

I using `LD_PRELOAD` to hook function like `LD_PRELOAD=my_lib.so ./my_exec`

How can I unload `my_lib.so` when the hook function called without restart the process?

Answer (score 1):

You can't unload a preloaded libraray.

However what you could do is implement a `my_lib_shim.so` as wrapper-shim that later on loads the library proper using `dlopen` and populate the hooks with `dlsym`. Unloading then was possible with `dlclose`.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. For example I hook on `fopen` with my_lib.so and if while the process running I want to unload my_lib.so.   canI do that?